# Object ID from a URL

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm trying to get the Facebook Object ID from a URL in order to post comments to that object.  The following FQL query on the object_url table gives the wrong ID:

```
SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url="http://wonderwall.msn.com/music/bret-michaels-kristi-gibson-call-off-engagement-1696257.story"
```

http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20id%20from%20object_url%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwonderwall.msn.com%2Fmusic%2Fbret-michaels-kristi-gibson-call-off-engagement-1696257.story%22

ie, 10151964793305004

The right ID is visible from the comments feed given here under paging.next: http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwonderwall.msn.com%2Fmusic%2Fbret-michaels-kristi-gibson-call-off-engagement-1696257.story

ie, 10151964793330004

I need the numeric id in order to post a comment for this page, and but I can't simply get it from the second link because if there are no comments it will not appear.

Comment: If it is possible, I will wait for an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason facebook has a separate "comments id" called `comments_fbid` in the `link_stat` table, so the first query should have been this:

```
SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://wonderwall.msn.com/music/bret-michaels-kristi-gibson-call-off-engagement-1696257.story"
```